# Open URL but point to main directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hashtag

I'm going to do a website with AJAX.

At the moment i change my main content with '#':

e.g. `example.com/#home` --> `example.com/#site1`
I managed it to change the content at the moment the hashtag changes.

But now i want to use a method i know from google.
`example.com/home/` --> `example.com/site1/`

I know so far how to change the URL without reloding the page. ([Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)) My problem is if the user reloads the site or uses the navigation buttons, he will land on `example.com/site1/index.php` and not on `example.com/index.php`.

BUT it is important that the data (site1) is send to the script.

I hope you can understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something on the server side (`.htaccess` for example) to return your index.php no matter what the url is.

See here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392502/1030527